# How to send transaction with web3.eth.sendTransaction?

Tags: web3js, transactions

I am sending ether by using `web3.eth.sendTransaction`.
But when I send, there is error:

`Failed to check for transaction receipt:`

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: base_address,
    to: withdrawer,
    gasLimit: GASLIMIT,
    gasPrice: GASPRICE,
    value: wei_val
})
.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('error', err);
    res.json({error: "Sending error"});
})
.on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){

 })
 .on('receipt', function(receipt){
     var transactionHash = receipt.transactionHash;
     console.log('transactionHash', transactionHash);

 })
 .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ 

  });
```

I think I can see the transactionHash in console, but error is coming.
How can I do it?

Comment: I think it depends on Geth version.
I installed geth 1.8.1-stable
In this geth version, I can't use `sendTransaction`?

Comment: It indeed seems to be geth issue, see https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1255 for workarounds. Note that according to some comments the transaction gets through eventually